# Deserialize JSON into a Objects by property name aswell as JsonProperty

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a large amount of JSON data stored in a database.
To reduce the size of this data we are using [JsonProperty("")] tags.
However legacy properties still use the full name, and changing those to a tag based system requires extensive workaround to slowly rebuilt the data when it's accessed.

Is there a setting or easy way to deserialize into a property based on its name and the JsonProperty tag.

Or will I have to write a custom deserializer?

Example:

This JSON

```
{
    "coins": {
        "Total": 1004
    }
}
```

Will not deserialize into this object

```
[JsonProperty("c")]
public Coins coins { get; set;}

public Class Coins
{
    public int Total { get; set;}
}
```

Removing the `[JsonProperty("c")]` allows it to deserialize again.
However to convert the existing data we have to a more space efficient method I need to be able to read the existing data via the property name while the JsonProperty tag is on

Comment: What do you mean by that? When deserializing you don't have to decorate with `JsonProperty` - the library will use the name of the property (case insensitive) by default if it can find a match. And by JSON data stored in a database are you talking something like Mongo, or do you have actual JSON strings stored in something like MSQL?

Comment: @MichaelJones It is in DynamoDB, so like Mongo.
When a property has a JsonProperty tag it will override the name, so when an older stored object using the property name as the JSON token is deserialized it wont use that property.

I'll add an example to the OP explaining better what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive I'm following, but what I think is going on is that you have this JSON:

```
{
    "coins": {
        "Total": 1004
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "c": {
        "Total": 1004
    }
}
```

And models like this:

```cs
public class CoinsWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public Coins coins { get; set;}
}

public class Coins
{
    public int Total { get; set;}
}
```

**Solution 1 - Create Secondary Propety**

```cs
public class CoinsWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public Coins coins { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("coins")]
    private Coins legacyCoins { set { coins = value; } }
}
```

And then when you deserialize it will assign the value to coins, and when you serialize it will ignore legacyCoins.

---

**Solution 2 - use `JsonExtensionData` and reflection to 'map' automatically**

I decided to have a bit of fun with this... obviously you'll need to be careful with this because if your naming has any overlap you could cause things to blow up pretty easily.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
        ""coins"": {
            ""Total"": 1004
        }
    }";

    var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoinsWrapper>(json);
    wrapper.Dump();
}

public class CoinsWrapper : LegacyAutoMap
{
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public Coins coins { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LegacyAutoMap
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (_additionalData == null) return;
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var entry in _additionalData)
        {
            var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == entry.Key.ToLowerInvariant());
            if (prop == null) continue;

            JToken token = entry.Value;
            MethodInfo ifn = typeof(JToken).GetMethod("ToObject", new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod(new[] { prop.PropertyType });
            prop.SetValue(this, ifn.Invoke(token, null));
        }
        _additionalData = null;
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 3 - Introduce a new custom attribute combined with solution 2**

This is the most flexible and probably safest solution. Flexible because you can provide multiple alternate names, and safest because only those fields you specify will be 'auto mapped'.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string json = @"
[
    {
        ""coins"": 
        {
            ""Total"": 1004
        }
    },
    {
        ""c"": 
        {
            ""Total"": 1004
        }
    },
    {
        ""coinz"": 
        {
            ""Total"": 1004
        }
    }
]";

    var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoinsWrapper[]>(json);
    wrapper.Dump();
}

public class CoinsWrapper : LegacyAutoMap
{
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    [AlternateJSONName("coins")]
    [AlternateJSONName("coinz")]
    public Coins coins { get; set; }
}

public class Coins
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LegacyAutoMap
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (_additionalData == null) return;

        var mappableProps = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(AlternateJSONNameAttribute)))
            .Select(p =>
            {
                var attrs = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AlternateJSONNameAttribute)).Cast<AlternateJSONNameAttribute>();
                return attrs.Select(attr => new { AlternateName = attr.JSONKey.ToLowerInvariant(), Property = p });
            })
            .SelectMany(attrs => attrs);

        foreach (var entry in _additionalData)
        {
            var prop = mappableProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.AlternateName == entry.Key.ToLowerInvariant());
            if (prop == null) continue;

            JToken token = entry.Value;
            MethodInfo ifn = typeof(JToken).GetMethod("ToObject", new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod(new[] { prop.Property.PropertyType });
            prop.Property.SetValue(this, ifn.Invoke(token, null));
        }
        _additionalData = null;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AlternateJSONNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string JSONKey { get; }

    public AlternateJSONNameAttribute(string keyName)
    {
        this.JSONKey = keyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works really well, but I was hoping there was a setting in the deserializer or something that would work for all the properties. As there is a lot of properties in the data that need changing, and creating a handler property for every single one isn't ideal.

Comment: @JakeHayton I’ve updated my answer with a potential solution via an abstract class. You might consider taking it further and creating a custom attribute like `AlternateJsonName` and key off of that instead of the property name.

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was hoping for. I tried using the `[JsonExtensionData]` when you mentioned it in your original answer, but I was barking up the wrong tree with my implementation.

Comment: @JakeHayton I added an example of what I meant about adding a custom attribute. You might also needs to consider some try/catch logic when doing your `ToObject`, unless you want an exception thrown if for some reason a key's data type doesn't match

Answer (score -1):

Here is a general purpose deserialization class which can be use for any object

```
public class JsonHelper
 {         
     public static string JsonSerializer<T> (T t)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
         ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
         string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
         ms.Close();
         return jsonString;
     }  

     public static T JsonDeserialize<T> (string jsonString)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
         T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
         return obj;
     }
 }
```

By using this, you can deserialize any data to any class,

```
Student student = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<Student>(jsonStudent);
```

For more detail with example [see this blog](http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/195/deserialize-json-data-in-c-according-to-my-table-structure)

Comment: This doesnt solve my issue, I have updated the OP with an example of the issue I am facing.

Comment: This doesn't make use of JSON.net, which the question specified (in the tags). Nor does this solve the use case.